# Database sequences: Why incrementing by other than 1?

Tags: sql, database, sequence, auto-increment

I am wondering, why you should use an `increment by` something other that "1".

I know, that sequences can have gaps, for example because of caching, but this is not what I am asking now. I would like to know, why it should be better to use

```
create sequence SEQ start with 1 increment by 20
```

instead of

```
create sequence SEQ start with 1 increment by 1
```

Oracle, I think, for example uses an increment of 20, JPA (Java Persistence API) defines sequences with an increment of 50 by default.

- But what is the advantage?
- And what value should I use?

Thank you for answering! Kind regards!

Comment: Because there might be some applications that want sequences incremented by arbitrary values, and there is no reason to force the users of such sequences to do arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you for answering! With "applications" you mean _software applications_ that use the database/sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose I know is that if you have a dataset stored on 20 database servers. If they each incremented by 1, they'd generate the same values, and it would be hard to merge the data if you ever need to do that.

If each of the 20 servers increment by 20, and each one starts at a different offset, then they'll all allocate distinct id's. So if you need to merge them for reports, or as you re-build your set of servers, you won't have conflicts.

Comment: Thank you! So people often do that `increment by` just, because _maybe_ they some day want to use several servers? So for a little database it is not necessary, but also does not have any disadvantages?

Comment: @eisenbahnfan . . . No.  The functionality is there so the sequences can readily support handling multiple servers (in this case).

Comment: The disadvantage is that you'll run out of integers 20 times faster.

Comment: @BillKarwin ... what, in practice, does not really matter, because the `maxvalue` ist 10^27 (with `increment by 50`), so I could still use 2*10^25 values. What increment value would you recommend?

Comment: There's no reason to increment by large amounts when you only have 1 server. When you get multiple servers, you'd change the increment on all of them at at that time, and it would apply to rows created after the reconfiguration.

Comment: @eisenbahnfan, I am not sure the 20 or 50 values refer to sequence increment. As I read, it seems to refer to the size of blocks of id's reserved to allocate to new rows, *instead* of using a sequence. They may still be allocated 1 at a time out of this block of 20 or 50. I think you should read more about it before making a decision.